# Finding a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

**Question**: For $z \in \mathbb{C}^{N+1}$ and $j \in \{1,\dots,N\}$, let $z(j) \in \mathbb{C}^N$ be the tuple obtained by omitting the $j^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of $z$. Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ be open and define $$D_j=\{z \in \mathbb{C}^{N+1}: z(j),z(j+1) \in D\}.$$ For any holomorphic function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and each $j$, show that there exists a unique holomorphic function $\Delta_jf: D_j \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $$\Delta_jf=\frac{f(z(j+1))-f(z(j))}{z_j-z_{j+1}}$$ where $z_j\neq z_{j+1}$.

I don't know how to begin solving this, even in the simplest case with $N=1$ I become stuck. It looks suspiciously like some kind of mean value theorem although that may just be coincidence.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Define $\Delta_j(f)=\int_0^1{(\partial_{z_j}f)((1-t)z(j)+tz(j+1))\,dt}$ when $z_j$ and $z_{j+1}$ close and the regular way otherwise.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer please? I'm afraid I still don't understand. What do you mean by "close" and the "regular way"?

Comment: Prove that $U=\{z \in D_j,\,[z(j),z(j+1)] \subset D\}$ is an open subset of $D_j$. Define $\Delta_jf$ with the integral in my comment on $U$, and with your definition on $D_j \cap \{z_j \neq z_{j+1}\}$.